# cap deploy:setup bash: /usr/bin/cap: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I am getting this error

```
cap deploy:setup
bash: /usr/bin/cap: No such file or directory
```

gem list:--

```
capistrano (2.5.19)
capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
```

Previously i was getting an issue like:--

```
 cap deploy:setup
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require': no such file to load -- capistrano/ext/multistage (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
from ./config/deploy.rb:2:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from Capfile:3:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:64:in `load_recipes'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:64:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:64:in `load_recipes'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:30:in `execute!'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
from /usr/bin/cap:4
```

So i did:--

```
 sudo gem uninstall capistrano
 sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/cap
 sudo gem install capistrano-ext
 sudo gem install capistrano
```

so i m getting the eror i specified earlier:--

```
cap deploy:setup
bash: /usr/bin/cap: No such file or directory
```

How can fix this issue. I am not able to find this using google etc.

Comment: Try restarting your bash terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove both the gems and install it again..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bundler, try executing in the bundle context:
    `bundle exec cap deploy:setup`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that `ls -l /usr/bin/cap` actually shows a small file there.

Capistrano is written in Ruby and [the first line of the file will be a shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) that probably references the Ruby interpreter with an absolute path name.

Type `head -1 cap` or `cat cap` and see if the Ruby interpreter is really located where the `cap` script thinks it is. If not, you can install a gem on top of itself, so just install capistrano again.

Comment: for first ie ls -l /usr/bin/cap :-ls: cannot access /usr/bin/cap: No such file or directory

Comment: and for head -1 cap or cat cap:-- cat:--------- head: cannot open `cap' for reading: No such file or directory and  cap: No such file or directory

Comment: I'm encountering exactly the same issue. There is no file in /usr/bin/cap